# Create new numpy array by duplicating each item in an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, for-loop

I would like to create a new [numpy](https://numpy.org/) array by repeating each item in another array by a given number of times (`n`). I am currently doing this with a for loop and `.extend()` with lists but this is not really efficient, especially for very large arrays.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```py
def expandArray(array, n):
    new_array = []
    for item in array:
        new_array.extend([item] * n)
    new_array = np.array(new_array)
    return new_array


print(expandArray([1,2,3,4], 3)
```

```
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
```

Comment: Numpy's `repeat`, is exactly what you want https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a duplicated array with the `numpy.repeat` function.

```
array = np.array([1,2,3,4])

new_array = np.repeat(array, repeats=3, axis=None)
print(new_array)

array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4])


new_array = np.repeat(array.reshape(-1,1).transpose(), repeats=3, axis=0).flatten()
print(new_array)

array([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why, but this code runs faster than **np.repeat** for me:

```
def expandArray(array, n):
    return np.concatenate([array for i in range(0,n)])
```

I ran this little benchmark:

```
arr1 = np.random.rand(100000)
%timeit expandArray(arr1, 5)

1.07 ms ± 25.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

And **np.repeat** gives this result:

```
%timeit np.repeat(arr1,5)

2.45 ms ± 148 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Your solution produces a different array `[1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4]`. If their orders are not required then this is a good solution.

Comment: The order is very important.